# Index out of range error in deck shuffling algorithm

Tags: python, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm writing a python version of the board Game *Onitama*, and I'm currently trying to write a function to shuffle the cards:

```
temp_deck = onitama_deck.deck
print(temp_deck)
print(len(onitama_deck.deck))
print(len(temp_deck))
for i in range(len(temp_deck)):
    next_card = temp_deck[random.randrange(0, len(temp_deck))]
    deck.deck[i] = next_card
    temp_deck.remove(next_card)
print(onitama_deck.deck)
```

Both onitama_deck.deck and temp_deck are lists, but when I run the program with a deck containing the values from 1-10, i get the following output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
10
10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "onitama.py", line 33, in <module>
    deck.shuffle()
  File "onitama.py", line 25, in shuffle
    onitama_deck.deck[i] = next_card
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

At first I was wondering why i was too big, so I tried printing both lists. For some reason, each iteration the lowest odd number is removed from temp_deck, and then onitama_deck.deck is set equal to temp_deck, like this:

```
iteration: 1
temp_deck: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
deck: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

iteration: 2
temp_deck: [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
deck: [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

iteration: 3
temp_deck: [2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
deck: [2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

iteration: 4
temp_deck: [2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10]
deck: [2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10]

iteration: 5
temp_deck: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
deck: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

And then I get the index out of range error. Can anyway explain the flaw in my logic? Thanks for the help.

Comment: How do you expect us to help if you don't show the code where the error originates?

Comment: Why not just use random.shuffle(), that's what it is intended for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `temp_deck` isn't a copy of the deck, but is a reference to the *same* deck:

```
temp_deck = onitama_deck.deck
```

To make a copy, you can change this to:

```
temp_deck = list(onitama_deck.deck)
```